# Plugin architecture for Android app providing complex objects

Tags: android

For one of my projects, I'm facing a real problem about creating plugins for my main app.
I already saw AIDL part, but that's not enough.
Indeed, I'm trying to create plugins which are class implementing common interface like this :

```
interface I :
    - impl1
    - impl2
    - impl3
```

At this point I studied the AIDL but I was facing the problem that my interface need some complex Objects (in methods, like Map, or android's complex class like BT...) and AIDL doesn't accept this...

The main Application is to manage UI and data from this common interface, and will use plugins to instanciate these classes implementing the interface.
Basic solution is to put all obejcts in main app, but I need something more flexible, with a real plugin system... And I'm really new about this feature...!

```
MainApp (List<I> iS) <= [SOMETHING] => Plugins (i1, i2, i3)
```

Can someone help me, maybe with the architecture, or library/something else ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "Basic solution is to put all obejcts in main app, but I need something more flexible, with a real plugin system" -- why?

Comment: Because it's a need for the app i'm developping. Can't really be more specific about this but the aim is to be able to activate a plugin for some persons, not for everyone, and to be able to add a new plugin easily without "redeploying"/updating APK for everyone

Comment: Where and how are you planning on distributing the app? It isn't the Play Store, as what you are describing is not allowed.

Comment: Yep, not in playstore. Can't be more precise about this now ^^
But maybe this question has no answer and I've to review the architecture of my app !

Comment: The reason for the push-back is that it is very difficult to secure what you are describing. You are certainly welcome to look into `DexClassLoader` and craft a plugin mechanism based upon it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look ! 
But is this a confirmation that IPC cannot perform this kind of architecture ? (in fact I think the base of IPC and AIDL is exactly what I need, but with possibility of using more complex data types...)

Comment: "But is this a confirmation that IPC cannot perform this kind of architecture ?" -- it can, but you need to design your API to be coarse-grained (to minimize IPC overhead) and within the confines of AIDL (to work with the data types that you have access to).